# Date format in pl sql procedure pass into a string

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am having trouble to pass the right date format to my procedure. I did search on the forum but did not find a solution. When I extract the value in my string I get the following result

```
select *
  from (select a.col1,
               a.col2,
               a.col3,
               dense_rank() over(order by a.col2) as TheRank,
               round((count(*) over(order by a.col2)), 1) as UniqueRank
          from abt_t a
         where a.col4 >= to_date(05 - JAN - 98, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
           and a.col4 <= 05 - JAN - 98
           and (a.col2 <= '15:59' and a.col2 >= '09:30')
         order by 1 asc, 2)
 where TheRank = 390
   and UniqueRank = 05 - JAN - 98
```

the value 05 - JAN - 98 is pretty different then the one I have initiated `p_start_dt date:= to_date('1998-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD');`

I have tried

Here is my procedure :

```
create or replace procedure GET_VOL_OPTION_test is

BEGIN
  DECLARE
  -- Local variables here
w_sqlcode                           number := 0;
w_sqlerrm                            char(500) := '';
query_str VARCHAR2(2000);
TYPE cur_typ IS  ref CURSOR;
V_TABLE varchar2(200) :=NULL; 
c cur_typ;
inv_num NUMBER;
exp_dt date;
Curr_dt date;
inv_amt varchar2(5);
p_start_dt date:= to_date('1998-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
CURSOR CUR_OVRDDEF_PARAM_EN IS
select tname from OPT_TBL_NM_2015_T  order by tname;

BEGIN

  FOR XX IN CUR_OVRDDEF_PARAM_EN LOOP
    BEGIN
      ----


 query_str := 'select * from (select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3,' ||
              'dense_rank() over (order by a.col2) as TheRank,' ||
              'round((count(*) over (order by a.col2)),1) as UniqueRank ' ||
              /*'from '|| p_stock  || ' a' ||*/
              'from abc_t a' ||
              ' where a.col4 >=  to_date(' || to_char(p_start_dt)  || ', ''YYYY-MM-DD'')' || ' and ' || 'a.col4 <= ' || p_start_dt ||
              ' and (a.col2 <= ''15:59'' and a.col2 >= ''09:30'')' ||
              'order by 1 asc,2)' ||
              'where TheRank = 390 and UniqueRank = ' || p_start_dt;    
    OPEN c FOR query_str ;
    LOOP
        FETCH c INTO inv_num, exp_dt, curr_dt, inv_amt;

        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        -- process row here

    END LOOP;

   /*  EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
       END;*/

      EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN 
            w_sqlcode := SQLCODE;
            w_sqlerrm := SQLERRM;
        END;
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;
  END;
  END;
```

I am using oracle 12. If you need more information, please don't hesitate.

Regards,

Christian

Comment: BTW: `round(count(*), 1)`?` The result of `count` is an integer, so rounding this to one decimal place does absolutely nothing. Moreover, `UniqueRank` is an integer as mentioned, so what is `and UniqueRank = ' || p_start_dt` supposed to do?

Comment: Why are you converting your date variable to a string just to convert it to a date again; why are you concatenating the values into the dynamic string instead of using bind variables; why are you comparing the UniqueRank number with your date; and why are you using dynamic SQL at all here? And why do you appear to be storing dates and times in separate columns?

Comment: I should have mention that the sql is not logic. I was trying to make my date work. I am using pl sql developer and in debug mode I stop just after the query_str and look at the value to see if my date format is correct. Sorry for misguiding you with the logic, will mention next time if the situation apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `to_char(p_start_dt)` without a format mask (or, later, using string concatenation on the dates) and Oracle will convert the date to a string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. As you have found, this is probably set to `DD-MON-YY` and is causing you issues. If you are going to convert dates to strings and embed it into the dynamic SQL then you need to specify the format mask for the conversion (i.e. `TO_CHAR( p_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )`); however, a better solution would be to:

Use bind variables in your dynamic SQL and then just pass the date in when you open the cursor:

```
DECLARE
  -- Local variables here
  w_sqlcode  number := 0;
  w_sqlerrm  char(500) := '';
  query_str  VARCHAR2(2000)
               := 'select * from (select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3,' ||
                  'dense_rank() over (order by a.col2) as TheRank,' ||
                  'count(*) over (order by a.col2) as UniqueRank' ||
                  ' from abc_t a' ||
                  ' where a.col4 BETWEEN :start_dt AND :start_dt' ||
                  ' and (a.col2 <= ''15:59'' and a.col2 >= ''09:30'')' ||
                  'order by 1 asc,2)' ||
                  'where TheRank = 390 and UniqueRank = :start_dt';
  c          SYS_REFCURSOR;
  inv_num    NUMBER;
  exp_dt     DATE;
  Curr_dt    DATE;
  inv_amt    VARCHAR2(5);
  p_start_dt DATE := DATE '1998-01-05';
  CURSOR CUR_OVRDDEF_PARAM_EN IS
    select tname from OPT_TBL_NM_2015_T  order by tname;
BEGIN
  FOR XX IN CUR_OVRDDEF_PARAM_EN LOOP
    BEGIN
      OPEN c FOR query_str USING p_start_dt;
      LOOP
        FETCH c INTO inv_num, exp_dt, curr_dt, inv_amt;

        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        -- process row here
      END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        w_sqlcode := SQLCODE;
        w_sqlerrm := SQLERRM;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Also, why are you comparing `UniqueRank` to a date value?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the comparative was only to try different version of the result. Your point is valid, but it will not be used at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line where you create the date comparision:

```
' where a.col4 >=  to_date(' || to_char(p_start_dt)  || ', ''YYYY-MM-DD'')' || ' and ' || 'a.col4 <= ' || p_start_dt ||
```

and you get

```
where a.col4 >= to_date(05 - JAN - 98, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and a.col4 <= 05 - JAN - 98
```

So obviously your standard date format is 'DD - MON - RR'. Why do you even rely on a setting? You should specify the format in `to_char`, such as:

```
to_char(p_start_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

rather than using `to_char(p_start_dt)` or `p_start_dt` (which is both the same; a date converted to string using the default setting).

You are also missing quotes. The correct syntax would have been:

```
' where a.col4 >= to_date(''' || to_char(p_start_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  || ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD'') and ' ||
       'a.col4 <= to_date(''' || to_char(p_start_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  || ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD'')' ||
```

or simpler with ISO date literals:

```
' where a.col4 >= date ''' || to_char(p_start_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ''' and ' ||
       'a.col4 <= date ''' || to_char(p_start_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''' ||
```

which is of course the same as

```
' where a.col4 = date ''' || to_char(p_start_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''' ||
```